# unable to run python scripts through AMPPS server

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, ampps

I'm trying to deploy my python application on ampps server. I'm facing problem with changes to be made in my httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName myopinion 

DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\wsgi-app" 

WSGIScriptAlias /myapp "C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\wsgi-app\myopinion.wsgi" 
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\wsgi-app"> 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have created a new folder wsgi_app at the location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\wsgi_app".

The wsgi_app folder holds my .wsgi file and the python script that I want to deploy.

After doing all this i restarted my server and run the url "http://192.168.0.103/myapp/ques/2".

It gives me: 
     403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /myapp/ques/2 on this server.

someone please guide me..

Comment: ``ServerName`` is wrong for a start. It is meant to be a host name only, not an IP address with port. Nor is ``ServerAlias`` meant to be an IP address. Check the Apache HTTPD documentation for examples.

Comment: Serveralias is commented....and i changed the server name to the hostname associated with the ip

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: The URL you use should use the same hostname you have specified in ``ServerName``, not an IP address.

Comment: It gives the same result....can u tell me if there is some particular point where i should place the virtual host code

Comment: sir @dumpleton can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477275/ampps-internal-server-error